# Check multiple words in a string using Contains method

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I want to check multiple words in a string and want to replace them. Suppose that my string is

```
str= 20148(R)/(work)24553(r)
if(str.contains(("R)" || str.Contains("(work)"))
{
   //Here I have to replace (R) and (Work) with space "". 
   // so that my string should be like this 20148/24553
}
```

How can check multiple words not by using loops, and in one flow. 
I am new to c#. Please help me out

Comment: Why don't just chain them: `str = str.Replace("(R)", "").Replace("(work)", "");`

Comment: Use the class you used to tag this question: RegEx. Take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the if, just do:

```
var newStr = str.Replace("(R)"," ").Replace("(work)"," ");
```

If you want a space as you say or:

```
var newStr = str.Replace("(R)",string.Empty).Replace("(work)",string.Empty);
```

If you want an empty string.

Comment: This won't replace the lowercase `(r)` so you'd need to chain that as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
string str = "20148(R)/(work)24553(r)";
string str2 = Regex.Replace(str, "[(](?:R|work)[)]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.Writeline(str2); //prints 20148/24553
```

This says take the string `str` and match the pattern `[(R|work)]` and replace any instances with `""` ignoring the case of the input string when doing the comparison (so it matches `(R)` and `(r)`).

Comment: No this match characters '(' and 'R' and '|' and 'w' and 'o' and 'r' and 'k' and ')'

Comment: @Rawling - apologies. Code is updated, I rushed testing the code!

Comment: Why have you added `\\b`s to your answer?

Comment: @Rawling - I mistakenly thought I needed it to match a whole word when my original wasn't working (when it was matching each character). Code updated.

Answer (score 1):

Put `R` and `r` inside a character class to match both letters.

```
string str = "20148(R)/(work)24553(r)";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\((?:[Rr]|work)\)", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/eoS3hm)

**OR**

```
string str = "20148(R)/(work)24553(r)";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?i)\((?:R|work)\)", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/BJgmGi)

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `(?i)` (*i modifier*) would turn on the case-insensitive mode. So it would match both upper and lowercase letters.
- `\(` Matches a literal `(` symbol.
- `(?:)` Non-capturing group.
- `R|work` Matches a letter `R` or string `work`.(case-insensitive match)
- `\)` Matches a literal `)` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

With regex you can replace this

```
[(]\b(?:R|work)\b[)]
```

With empty string `""`

Edit:

```
 string str1 = "20148(R)/(work)24553(r)"; 
  string str2 = Regex.Replace(str1, "[(]\b(?:R|work)\b[)]", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  Console.Writeline(str2);
```

Comment: can u pls tell me elobarately

Comment: Why have you bothered with `\b`? The sequences `(R`, `(w`, `R)` and `k)` all contain `\b` so there is no need to check for it. (Also, you need two slashes in C# strings to achieve this.)